Make row 'Total' be the last row in pyspark dataframe
I have this dataframe



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




Total
1000
10000
null


1211
0
5000
1


1211
1000
5000
2



This code I tried for that:
df = (df.withColumn("Id", monotonically_increasing_id()+1)
           )

ANd when I try this to get my desire output:
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("Id", F.monotonically_increasing_id()+1)
windowSpec = W.orderBy("Id")
df1 = df1.withColumn("Id", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)).show()

This is the df I received:



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




Total
1400
1100
null


1211
800
500
1


1211
600
600
2



This is the df desire output:



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




1211
800
500
1


1211
600
600
2


Total
1400
1100
3



EDIT:
I tried the below answers from this post but I still got the same error. The values of Balance & Paid Amount is different from the 1st dataframe.
df1:



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




Total
2000
1500
null


1211
800
500
1


1211
600
600
2


1211
400
300
3


1211
200
100
4



codes I have tried:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

total_row = df.filter(F.col("Column A") == "Total")
other_rows = df.filter(F.col("Column A") != "Total")

final_df = other_rows.union(total_row)
final_df.show()


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

df1 = df1.withColumn("Flag", F.when(F.col("Column A") == "Total", 1).otherwise(0))
windowSpec = W.orderBy("Flag", "Column A")
df1 = df1.withColumn("Id", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
df1 = df1.drop("Flag")
df1.show()

same output:



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




1211
800
500
1


1211
800
500
2


1211
800
500
3


1211
200
100
4


Total
2000
1500
5



Correct result of Total for two columns, however, the values have changed.

You can create a separate one-row long dataframe with results and join it back with .unionAll()

Here is the sample data frame:



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




Total
1400
1100
NULL


1211
800
500
1


1211
600
600
2



You can use below code to get your required output data frame:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

df1 = df1.withColumn("Flag", F.when(F.col("Column A") == "Total", 1).otherwise(0))
windowSpec = W.orderBy("Flag", "Column A")
df1 = df1.withColumn("Id", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
df1 = df1.drop("Flag")
df1.show()

You will get the below dataframe as output:



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




1211
800
500
1


1211
600
600
2


Total
1400
1100
3




hi @Bhavani, thanks for this...however, I still got the same error. pls see EDIT in my post.

I will check it and let you know

@Kimchigirl I am getting correct values with my code which provided above.

YOU CAN TRY SEPERATING TORAL FROM THE DATAFRAME AND THEN UNIONING IT, WHICH SETS THE ROW IN THE BOTTOM
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

total_row = df.filter(F.col("Column A") == "Total")
other_rows = df.filter(F.col("Column A") != "Total")

final_df = other_rows.union(total_row)
final_df.show()

This will be the output:



Column A
Balance
Paid Amount
Id




1211
800
500
1


1211
600
600
2


Total
1400
1100
NULL




thank you for this, but I still got the error. @kedar U Shet
